# Deploying rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I'm learning RoR and trying to deploy my test app to heroku receiving next error:

```
Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without developmen
   You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
   the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * therubyracer (~> 0.9.3.beta1)
   * pg
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
```

!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

Please! Help!

Answer (score 7):

Have you committed your Gemfile.lock?

```
bundle install 
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -am "Add lock file"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: And before doing that, have you run `bundle install`?

Answer (score 2):

This error might be because you did not completely do bundle install.

First do

```
bundle install
```

Add `gem 'pg'` to the gem file and install the postgres gems and postgres on your local machine. If you dont want to install postgres on your local machine then add gem 'pg to production environment and run bundle install without test environment. Though heroku discourages this way of running your application. It is always better to use same database for running locally and in production. Installing postgres is pain but it is worth it.

```
Your ruby should be 1.9.2.
```

After installing all the dependencies and post gres on your machine do `bundle install` and add your gem file to heroku.

```
git add Gemfile
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit 
git push heroku master
```